# Display data in labels based on 1 record of data from database using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I want to display individual column values in separate labels.  I will only ever retrieve one record at any one time from my database.  How can I display the columns individually (i.e. not in a table and not using ng-repeat?)

So in a dropdown I could use:

```
data-ng-options="c.COLUMN_1 as c.COLUMN_1 for c in tableVarSetInJS"
```

but I don't want a dropdown, I want a label; something like:

```
<label data-ng-options="c.COLUMN_1 as c.COLUMN_1 for c in tableVarSetInJS">{{COLUMN_1}}</label>
```

and then in a separate label:

```
<label data-ng-options="c.COLUMN_2 as c.COLUMN_2 for c in tableVarSetInJS">{{COLUMN_2}}</label>
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the index 0 and use it's values directly.

```
<label>{{tableVarSetInJS[0].COLUMN_1}}</label>
<label>{{tableVarSetInJS[0].COLUMN_2}}</label>
```

Comment: Hello tpsilva, that is great thank you ever so much! :)

Comment: I've marked as answered but as my reputation score is < 15 it doesn't show... thank you!